# Is there a way to send form when element outside of form is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As title says, is there a way to send `form` when element outside of form is clicked? Plus, is it available without using `form` associated (`button`/`input` etc.) elements?

As example, can `form` be submitted when `div` is clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure:

```
<form name="myForm" action="" method="post">
    <!-- form inputs go here -->
</form>

<div id="formSubmit"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myForm = document.forms['myForm'];
    var formSubmit = document.getElementById('formSubmit');

    formSubmit.onclick = function(){
        myForm.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("formName").submit();
```

Comment: @Tom: this should work. Have you checked that your form **id** (not name) is what you pass to `getElementById`?

Answer (score 1):

To submit the form, you can call `form.submit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, assign an id to that form.

Once you click the desired element (button/input/div) you can do somthing like this in javascript

```
$("#YourFormId").submit();
```

Comment: You should specify that this is the "JQuery way" to do that. Other solutions (the ones using `document.getElementById`) do not need external libraries.

Comment: Check the tags, OP used JQuery :)

Comment: sorry didn't see that :) Still, better to specify for any other reader that does not necessarily look at the tags (like I did) and maybe arrives here from a Google link.